# gridview data binding itemptemplate field

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a data gridview which gathers data from database. The grid has 4 columns. one of the columns is the city name. In the sql code, I select the city code rather than city name.

I have converted this column into template field. In the edit mode, i was able to place drop down list and provide data binding in order for the user to be able to select the city.

however in itemtemplate mode i have label field. how can i provide data binding in which can pick up the data from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in some sort of following way(s)

**First approach**
Declare your datasource such as SQL Data Source / Object Data Source including the required value fields using sub queries or joins and assign it to the label as other values are being assigned.

**Second approach**
Declare the ItemTemplate as

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# LookupCity(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CityCode")) %>'></asp:Label> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the code-behind declare the LookupCity function as

```
protected string LookupCity(object idObj)
{
    string CityCode = idObj.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CityCode))
        // return if CityCode is not valid value
        return null;
    // find the corresponding name from SQL Data Source named SQLDS_City
    IEnumerator CityEnum = SQLDS_City.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments()).GetEnumerator();
    // loop through enum until required value is not found
    while (CityEnum.MoveNext())
    {
        DataRowView row = CityEnum.Current as DataRowView;
        if ((string)row["CityCode"].ToString() == CityCode)
            return string.Concat(row["CityName"].ToString());
    }
    // return code if it is not found in the enum
    return CityCode;
}
```

**Third approach**
You may use the DropDownList control for ItemTemplate also. An example can be found here [Bind-DropDownList-in-ItemTemplate-of-TemplateField-in-ASPNet-GridView](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-DropDownList-in-ItemTemplate-of-TemplateField-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx). To restrict the user from changing the value in ItemTemplate you may keep it **disabled** for display purpose only.